# Differential Coefficients Quotient Rule

Tags: calculus, differential

Have i do this correctly?? Struggling a little with this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There a bunch of typos in there. But for the most part, yeah, it's all fine.

Comment: Please type your question rather than posting an image since images cannot be searched.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I got this here $$4\,{\frac {\cos \left( 5\,x \right) }{{x}^{4}}}-{\frac {16\,\sin
 \left( 5\,x \right) }{5\,{x}^{5}}}
$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner you got a different answer. Is this because you derived it more than i did?

Answer (score 1):

Using the quotient and the chain rule we get
$$y'=\frac{4}{5}\frac{\cos(5x)\cdot 5\cdot x^4-\sin(5x)\cdot 4x^3}{x^8}$$